# How do I turn a .NET System.String into a string usable by VBScript?

Tags: .net, interop, vbscript

I'm trying to call a .NET component using interop from a classic ASP page (VBScript).  If a .NET function returns a "System.String", is there a way for me to use that as a VBScript string? Is there something I need to do to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to convert it.  System.String should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to convert it to anything special. Just returning a System.String will be fine